# How Can I Obtain A users geographic coordinates without USing GPS and display It on A Google Maps Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

Moreover, How does Uber Get Its Accurate User Location Without GPS?
Does it Use the COARSE_LOCATION, or FINE_LOCATION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uber does use your GPS. See its permission requirements on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab&hl=en):

> Location
>
> - approximate location (network-based)
> - precise location (GPS and network-based)

Nonetheless, you can get an approximate location without using GPS by using [`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

Answer (score 0):

you can read these documents:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi